# Can't add Bootstrap Tab into php code

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

If I add this Bootstrap Tab into html code, it works perfectly:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="#hello" data-toggle="tab">Hello</a></li>
   <li><a href="#empty" data-toggle="tab">Empty</a></li>
</ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="hello">
        <h3>Hello my Friend!</h3>
        <p>hello</p>
      </div><!-- @end #hello -->

      <div class="tab-pane" id="empty">
        <h3>Just gonna be empty...</h3>

        <p>Yup. Nothin' here.</p>
      </div><!-- @end #empty -->
    </div>
```

But in those tap I need to connect to my database so show some information, my code is:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#facilities" data-toggle="tab">Facilities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#fee" data-toggle="tab">Course Fee</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="facilities">
        <h3>Just gonna be empty...</h3>        
        <p>Yup. Nothin' here.</p>
        <?php echo "<table>";
            $userpic = '<img src="images/user.png"/>';
            while ($roww = mysqli_fetch_array($usercomment)){
                $cm_fac = $roww['facilities'];
                $name = $roww['UserName'];
                $time = $roww['CmtDate'];
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>';
                        //i put some info here as table
                    echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </div><!-- end of facilities-->

    <div class="tab-pane" id="fee">
        <h3>Hello my Friend!</h3>
        <p>hello</p>
        <?php echo "<table>";
            $userpic = '<img src="images/user.png"/>';
            while ($roww = mysqli_fetch_array($usercomment)){
                $cm_fee = $roww['fee'];
                $name = $roww['UserName'];
                $time = $roww['CmtDate'];
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>';
                        //some info here too
                    echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </div><!-- end of fee-->

</div> <!--end of tab-content-->
```

but it doesn't work. Can anyone show me my problem? 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe can try this:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="fee">
  <h3>Hello my Friend!</h3>
  <p>hello</p>

<!-- open the 'while' -->
  <?php 
    while ($roww = mysqli_fetch_array($usercomment)){ 
      $cm_fac = $roww['facilities'];
      $name = $roww['UserName'];
      $time = $roww['CmtDate'];
  ?>

<!-- your table -->
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo "your data here"; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<?php } ?> <!-- close the 'while' here -->
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work WQuaniran, situation is the same as my old code :(

Comment: Wait, do you want the tabs from the database?

Comment: Yes, for more specific, each tabs will display a different part of users' comments, which I stored in my database

Answer (score 0):

- Check results of your query.
- You can use `$roww = mysqli_fetch_array($usercomment, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` to fetch data.

Comment: My results from $roww is ok, because I can display users' comments successfully using my above code, the problem only happend when I try to create another tab to display another part of my data. I try to add MYSQLI_ASSOC but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Thôi nói tiếng việt đi. :D. Bạn cần lấy data từ database ra phải không?